# c# selenium : Getting WebdriverException when element not found

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In c# Selenium, I am using FindElement to find an element which is not present in the page but instead of getting `NoSuchElementException` I get `WebDriverException`

The Exception is:

```
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at org.myorg.DriverUtils.FindElement(By by, Boolean raiseException, Boolean setTestFail, Int32 currentAttempt)
```

The webdriver:

```
var downloadDir = "path to downoads";
var fxprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
fxprofile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
fxprofile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadDir);
fxprofile.SetPreference("browser.download.defaultFolder", downloadDir);
fxprofile.SetPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
fxprofile.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);


var profileM = new FirefoxProfileManager();
var profile = profileM.GetProfile("fxprofile");
var options = new FirefoxOptions();
var firefoxBinary = "path to firefox exe";

Driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, fxprofile);

try{
   Driver.FindElement(By.Id("non exeistant element"));
}
catch (NoSuchElementException e)
{
 // not hit
}
catch (WebDriverException e)
{
  //Hit here
  // Another thing i noticed is it takes almost a minute to actually throw this exception from the FindElement
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like exception but the stack trace of the exception, you need to post the exception also. Is your firefox launching?

Comment: yes firefox is launching.,When i navigated through the code(F10), It hit the WebdriverException

Answer (score 1):

I managed to debug and find the root cause.

Recently, I have used the following implicit wait for troubleshooting purposes and it ended up being the culprit

```
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

But when i create the `FirefoxDriver`, it initializes the base class `RemotewebDriver` with a default command timeout of 1 min

```
public FirefoxDriver(FirefoxBinary binary, FirefoxProfile profile)
      : this(binary, profile, RemoteWebDriver.DefaultCommandTimeout)
    {
    }
```

So, basically the `FirefoxCommandExecutor` has completed before the implicit wait that i have configured, and this made the driver to throw `WebdriverException` instead of `NosuchElementexception`. I reverted the implicit wait to 20 sec and the issue disappeared.

I am not sure if this is a how the `FirefoxDriver` should work or if this is bug. Perhaps `Firefoxdriver` should update the default command timeout when the imlicitwait is also set.

Answer (score 0):

The webdriverException timeout should be longer than the implicitWait timeout.

So the `NosuchElementexception` can be reached,

`ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))` is enough.

Note that `NosuchElementException` inherits from webdriverexception.